# Velocity Template is not detempletizing when a field inside object is accessed

Tags: java, velocity, vtl

I've written the below code, which basically needs to print `Hello simple Kishore` by substituting the values of `$string` and `$value.name` inside the template `Hello $string $value.name`.

It substitutes the value of `$string` however `$value.name` is never replaced.
 
I tried to detempletize the value of `$value` and that works fine with `TestClass$Sample@5594a1b5` as output, so the issue is with **Template not being able to access the fields in the object**.

Due to some constraints, I've to make use of [VelocityEngine.evaluate](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/VelocityEngine.html#evaluate(org.apache.velocity.context.Context,%20java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader)) itself and not [VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/VelocityEngine.html#mergeTemplate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.velocity.context.Context,%20java.io.Writer)).

**Code:**

```
class Sample {
    private String name = "Kishore";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String query = "Hello $string $value.name";

        VelocityContext vCtx = new VelocityContext();
        vCtx.put("string","simple");
        vCtx.put("value", new Sample());

        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
        engine.init();
        engine.evaluate(vCtx, out, "ERR:", new StringReader(query));

        System.out.println(out.toString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello simple $value.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this problem you should add `public` modifier for `Sample` class:

```
public class Sample {
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, I was just debugging it and found `ClassMap` class which creates a cache of all methods looks for public Modifier `if Modifier.isPublic(classToReflect.getModifiers())) populateMethodCacheWith(methodCache, classToReflect);` Thanks :)